# How to encode and replace JSON array values?

Tags: php, arrays, json, encryption

How to run all `access_token` values through the `encryptAES` function and replace the unencrypted token from the JSON array with the encrypted ones?

PHP encrypt:

```
$decrKey = "122P3051586a3561";
$decrIV = "233245548V1rr832";

function encryptAES($data,$key,$iv)
{
    {
$encr = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
return $encr;      
    }
```

JSON array:

```
{"data":[{"category":"Travel\/leisure","name":"Example","access_token":"111","perms":["ADMINISTER","EDIT_PROFILE","CREATE_CONTENT","MODERATE_CONTENT","CREATE_ADS","BASIC_ADMIN"],"id":"0"},{"category":"Company","name":"AnExample","access_token":"abc1234","perms":["ADMINISTER","EDIT_PROFILE","CREATE_CONTENT","MODERATE_CONTENT","CREATE_ADS","BASIC_ADMIN"],"id":"0"},{"category":"Technology","name":"Example Company Inc","access_token":"222","perms":["ADMINISTER","EDIT_PROFILE","CREATE_CONTENT","MODERATE_CONTENT","CREATE_ADS","BASIC_ADMIN"],"id":"0"}}
```

(Sorry for my english, I hope you undestand the question.)

Comment: You decode the JSON string into an array, replace the values and encode the array into a JSON string again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) to decode the JSON string into an array and use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) to apply the function on each array element:

```
$jsonArr = json_decode($str, true);

$result = array_map(function ($sub) use ($decrKey, $decrIV) {
    return encryptAES($decrKey, $sub['access_token'], $decrIV);
}, $jsonArr['data']);
```

Comment: Currently the result are only the 'access_token' values. How to keep the original JSON but replace the unencrypted with encrypted values?

Comment: I tried to combine both scripts, but the result are only the encrypted access_token: `$jsonArr = json_decode($resp, true); 

$result = array_map(function ($sub) use ($decrKey, $decrIV) {
    return encryptAES($sub['access_token'], $decrKey, $decrIV);
}, $jsonArr['data']);

foreach ($jsonArr['data'] as & $sub) {
    $sub['access_token'] = str_rot13($sub['access_token']);
}

echo $result;` What do I miss?

Comment: @Uli: No need to use `array_map()` if you're using `foreach`. Use one or the other, not both. If you want the whole array and not just `access_token`, use the `foreach` solution. And that `str_rot13()` bit was just an **example**. Replace it with your actual function call.

Comment: @Uli and Tom are the same person?

Comment: @AmalMurali Sorry, that was a co-workers accounts. Thanks for your help, the solution worked.